# Using springboot+JPA，the first time to save is too slow

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I used springboot+JPA+Hibernate to insert data. But the insertion speed of the first data is too slow, and it becomes faster later. I want to eliminate this situation and make all data insertions fast, including the first one. Is there any way to achieve this? Perhaps it can be achieved through configuration changes or some initialization operations. Below are my configurations, all the test code, and test result. And I have uploaded them to GitHub[https://github.com/MayflyShake/heart-test].

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>heart</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>heart-test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>heart-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tt_test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: root
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 5
      idle-timeout: 30000
      pool-name: SpringBootHikariCP
      auto-commit: true
      connection-timeout: 30000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

logging:
  config: config/log4j2-spring.xml
```

my entity:

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_order")
public class TestOrder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer orderId;

    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private String createTime;

    @Column(name = "params", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String params;

}
```

my dao:

```
@Repository
public interface TestOrderDao extends JpaRepository<TestOrder, Integer> {
}
```

my test main code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HeartApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(HeartApplication.class, args);
        TestOrderDao testOrderDao = context.getBean(TestOrderDao.class);
        String param = "{\"param1\":\"value1\"}";
        TestOrder t1 = new TestOrder();
        t1.setCreateTime("2024-02-29 09:53:00");
        t1.setParams(param);

        TestOrder t2 = new TestOrder();
        t2.setCreateTime("2024-02-29 09:53:00");
        t2.setParams(param);

        TestOrder t3 = new TestOrder();
        t3.setCreateTime("2024-02-29 09:53:00");
        t3.setParams(param);

        System.out.println("start test");

        new Thread(() -> {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
            testOrderDao.save(t1);
            long cost1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
            System.out.println("cost1:" + cost1);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long begin2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            testOrderDao.save(t2);
            long cost2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin2;
            System.out.println("cost2:" + cost2);

        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long begin3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            testOrderDao.save(t3);
            long cost3 = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin3;
            System.out.println("cost3:" + cost3);

        }).start();


        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and my test reuslt:
[image]
log:

```
19:37:44.909 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - SpringBootHikariCP - configuration:
19:37:44.911 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension................................false
19:37:44.911 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit................................true
19:37:44.911 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - catalog................................none
19:37:44.911 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql................................none
19:37:44.911 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery................................"SELECT 1"
19:37:44.911 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout................................30000
19:37:44.912 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource................................none
19:37:44.912 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName................................none
19:37:44.912 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI................................none
19:37:44.912 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties................................{password=<masked>}
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName................................"com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - exceptionOverrideClassName................................none
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties................................{}
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry................................none
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout................................30000
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout................................1
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries................................false
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl................................jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tt_test?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - keepaliveTime................................0
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - leakDetectionThreshold................................0
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maxLifetime................................1800000
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - maximumPoolSize................................10
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricRegistry................................none
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - metricsTrackerFactory................................none
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - minimumIdle................................5
19:37:44.913 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - password................................<masked>
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - poolName................................"SpringBootHikariCP"
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - readOnly................................false
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - registerMbeans................................false
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - scheduledExecutor................................none
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - schema................................none
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - threadFactory................................internal
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - transactionIsolation................................default
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - username................................"root"
19:37:44.915 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - validationTimeout................................5000
19:37:44.915 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - SpringBootHikariCP - Starting...
19:37:45.089 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7be71476
19:37:45.091 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - SpringBootHikariCP - Start completed.
19:37:45.099 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Database ->
       name : MySQL
    version : 5.5.62
      major : 5
      minor : 5
19:37:45.099 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - Driver ->
       name : MySQL Connector Java
    version : mysql-connector-java-6.0.6 ( Revision: 3dab84f4d9bede3cdd14d57b99e9e98a02a5b97d )
      major : 6
      minor : 0
19:37:45.099 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - JDBC version : 4.1
19:37:45.119 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
19:37:45.137 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.IdentifierHelperBuilder - JDBC driver metadata reported database stores quoted identifiers in more than one case
19:37:45.137 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.IdentifierHelperBuilder - IdentifierCaseStrategy for both quoted and unquoted identifiers was set to the same strategy [LOWER]; that will likely lead to problems in schema update and validation if using quoted identifiers
19:37:45.173 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope - Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@70c0a3d5] to MetadataBuildingContext [org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuildingContextRootImpl@5c8e67b9]
19:37:45.189 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Namespace - Created database namespace [logicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}, physicalName=Name{catalog=null, schema=null}]
19:37:45.198 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder
19:37:45.200 [SpringBootHikariCP housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
19:37:45.200 [SpringBootHikariCP housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - After cleanup  stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0)
19:37:45.207 [SpringBootHikariCP connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@435bedc7
19:37:45.211 [SpringBootHikariCP connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@37154be3
19:37:45.216 [SpringBootHikariCP connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@63751d50
19:37:45.221 [SpringBootHikariCP connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@62380e40
19:37:45.221 [SpringBootHikariCP connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - SpringBootHikariCP - After adding stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
19:37:45.228 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3DiscriminatorColumn{logicalColumnName'DTYPE', discriminatorTypeName='string'}
19:37:45.236 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Import with entity name TestOrder
19:37:45.239 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder on table test_order
19:37:45.261 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(test_order), mappingColumn=order_id, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
19:37:45.265 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl - Not known whether passed class name [com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder] is safe
19:37:45.266 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl - No temp ClassLoader provided; using live ClassLoader for loading potentially unsafe class : com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder
19:37:45.266 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - MetadataSourceProcessor property orderId with lazy=false
19:37:45.267 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder:orderId]
19:37:45.270 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for orderId
19:37:45.274 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property orderId
19:37:45.279 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper - #makeIdGenerator(org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue([org.hibernate.mapping.Column(order_id)]), orderId, identity, , ...)
19:37:45.280 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(test_order), mappingColumn=create_time, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
19:37:45.280 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - MetadataSourceProcessor property createTime with lazy=false
19:37:45.280 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder:createTime]
19:37:45.280 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for createTime
19:37:45.280 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property createTime
19:37:45.340 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table=org.hibernate.mapping.Table(test_order), mappingColumn=params, insertable=true, updatable=true, unique=false}
19:37:45.340 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - MetadataSourceProcessor property params with lazy=false
19:37:45.340 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder - Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder:params]
19:37:45.341 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - building SimpleValue for params
19:37:45.341 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property params
19:37:45.351 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Starting fillSimpleValue for orderId
19:37:45.351 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Starting fillSimpleValue for createTime
19:37:45.351 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Starting fillSimpleValue for params
19:37:45.352 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.mapping.PrimaryKey - Forcing column [order_id] to be non-null as it is part of the primary key for table [test_order]
19:37:45.391 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - Building session factory
19:37:45.392 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - SessionFactory name : null
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): enabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Statistics: disabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Default entity-mode: pojo
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Allow initialization of lazy state outside session : disabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Using BatchFetchStyle : LEGACY
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Default batch fetch size: -1
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 2
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Default null ordering: NONE
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - multi-tenancy strategy : NONE
19:37:45.393 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JTA Track by Thread: enabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Query language substitutions: {}
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Named query checking : enabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Second-level cache: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Second-level query cache: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Second-level query cache factory: null
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Second-level cache region prefix: null
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Optimize second-level cache for minimal puts: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Second-level cache direct-reference entries: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Automatic eviction of collection cache: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JDBC batch size: 15
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: enabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Scrollable result sets: enabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Wrap result sets: disabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
19:37:45.394 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JDBC result set fetch size: null
19:37:45.395 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Connection release mode: ON_CLOSE
19:37:45.395 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
19:37:45.395 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JPA compliance - query : disabled
19:37:45.395 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JPA compliance - closed-handling : disabled
19:37:45.395 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JPA compliance - lists : disabled
19:37:45.395 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Settings - JPA compliance - transactions : disabled
19:37:45.451 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl - EventListenerRegistry access via ServiceRegistry is deprecated.  Use `sessionFactory.getEventEngine().getListenerRegistry()` instead
19:37:45.451 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl - EventListenerRegistry access via ServiceRegistry is deprecated.  Use `sessionFactory.getEventEngine().getListenerRegistry()` instead
19:37:45.463 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
...
start test
19:37:51.556 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
19:37:51.556 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1291825417<open>)] for JPA transaction
19:37:51.558 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
19:37:51.558 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
19:37:51.560 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@d83e70a]
19:37:51.577 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
Hibernate: insert into test_order (create_time, params) values (?, ?)
19:37:51.579 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into test_order (create_time, params) values (?, ?)
19:37:51.588 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 28
19:37:51.588 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
19:37:51.591 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
19:37:51.591 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1291825417<open>)]
19:37:51.591 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
19:37:51.591 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
19:37:51.592 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
19:37:51.595 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
19:37:51.595 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
19:37:51.596 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
19:37:51.596 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder{orderId=28, createTime=2024-02-29 09:53:00, params={"param1":"value1"}}
19:37:51.600 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1291825417<open>)] after transaction
cost1:52
19:37:56.615 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
19:37:56.615 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1230646393<open>)] for JPA transaction
19:37:56.615 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
19:37:56.615 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
19:37:56.616 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@37ecaae]
Hibernate: insert into test_order (create_time, params) values (?, ?)
19:37:56.616 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
19:37:56.616 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into test_order (create_time, params) values (?, ?)
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 29
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1230646393<open>)]
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl - committing
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
19:37:56.617 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
19:37:56.619 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
19:37:56.619 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
19:37:56.619 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
19:37:56.619 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - com.example.heart.pojo.TestOrder{orderId=29, createTime=2024-02-29 09:53:00, params={"param1":"value1"}}
19:37:56.621 [Thread-10] DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1230646393<open>)] after transaction
cost2:6
```

Comment: During the first request the Hikari pool is also initialized, namely connections to the database are established. You can use an ApplicationLoader to initialize  connections at application startup.

Comment: @Serodv it isn't, the datasource is created at startup not on first request.

Comment: @Mayflyshake enable logging to see what is happening. Tip don't use `connection-test-query` HikariCP will use JDBC4 to validate the connection which should be faster.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have commented out all the Hikari configurations, but Spring Boot still uses Hikari. I have tried to switch the connection pool to Druid, but the situation has not improved. I suspect it's due to Hibernate.

Comment: Not sure why you commented all the hikari stuff, I only mentioned the query nothing else. Hikari is the default pool. But as stated enable logging and see what is happening. Looking at your output now shows you disabled all logging (there is no output).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have copied the logs above, but they seem to be normal.

Comment: Enable debug logging (or even trace). With regular INFO logging there is no real information. That being said Spring Boot 2.2 is very old I would suggest to use the latest 2.7.x (if you want to stay on the 2.x line) or use the newest 3.2.x instead. Also don't set `auto-commit` to `true` instead set it to `false`. Finally you might want to set the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true` to prevent messing with the auto-commit on the connection. And as mentioned do upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness you're experiencing with the first data insertion is likely due to Hibernate's first-level cache being empty. When you save the first object, Hibernate needs to perform additional operations like schema validation, SQL statement generation, and potential connection pool initialization. These initial activities can cause a delay for the first insertion. Subsequent insertions are faster because the necessary information is already cached by Hibernate, making the process more efficient.

Try This:

Enable Hibernate Cache
As you alreeady know Hibernate provides a built-in caching mechanism that can significantly improve performance, especially for frequently accessed data
So you need to enable caching by adding the following configuration to your application.yml file:
For More Info Follow this Link : https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/hibernate-l2-cache

```
jpa:
       hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
       hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
```

Comment: The Hibernate L2 Cache is suitable for more complex scenarios. In my case, with only one entity and a first-time insert problem, enabling the second-level cache may not provide any immediate benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This test is incorrect. Java and a lot of framework/library take some time to "warm up".

You are lucky to have a reproducible result after only three occurences.

We need more information on what you try to achieve.

As stated in jmh (test framework for jdk micro-benchmark), you have to warm up the jvm, hibernate, database... in order to get a reproducible result. Check examples on  [project jmh](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh?tab=readme-ov-file)

Furthermore, you can not create thread like this and expect them to run one after another. If you want to be almost sure to execute the request in order, you have to make the main thread sleep by removing the created thread. And even after that, you are not sure requests will be executed in the correct order because hibernate maybe use a first in last out queue (probably a first in first out but without analysing hibernate source code...). When you create thread or use a framework like hibernate, the order of requests is unpredictable even if most of the time it is predictable. These kind of bug are almost always seen in production and are really hard to diagnose.

Comment: My understanding is that once the Spring container has fully started (after SpringApplication.run(HeartApplication.class, args)), all "warm up", including connection pooling and JPA, have been completed. In fact, more than three occurences. The original program is quite complex, and I found that the first time's duration was exceptionally long after debugging. It turned out to be the "save" method causing the delay. To present the issue more clearly, I simplified the code and highlighted the relevant parts, creating a test code that I have uploaded to GitHub and show here.

Comment: Your understanding means nothing (no offense). Example: get(0) on a List implementation. it works but it has never been written explicitely that List implementation begin at index 0. If you remove index 0 and try to access it again, the list is not padded to the left but you will receive an ArrayOutOfBoundException or someting like this. To sum up, you can NOT rely on your understanding because there is far too many layer with the jvm, hibernate and spring that add more and more complexity.

Comment: To help you, i do not understand how a 56 ms operation can slow down an entire program apart if you call it million of times. If your diagnose is correct, the problem is probably related to parameterized queries (search spring parameterized queries performance on google). If you insert millions of line in a big program and have low performance, just try a minimal program that insert millions of test line (change the inserted value) into this table to check if it is the program, the method you use to insert or a sgbd-table problem.

Comment: Our system has an alarm program that reads the logs to determine if requests have timed out. I had originally planned to set the threshold at 10-20ms, but because the first insertion took significantly longer, I had to increase the threshold. Additionally, I would like to understand why this portion of the delay is not attributed to the startup of Spring Boot.

Comment: I have not attempted millions of times, but there are still several thousand tests performed each time with different data. The code snippet I posted is simply for the purpose of being more intuitive and concise.

Comment: Ok I begin to understand you are in a high latency environment. Warm up is not a problem because it is negligible time. But if it is a probleme for you, and there is no easy option to be sure to warm up the system before executing anything is to insert a value and delete it right away. Still, it does not prevent some slow down, because a connection to the db can be released if not used (either by sgbd or hibernate/spring). Most of framework (including sgbd) releases resources when not used, so it has to warm up again next time.

Comment: Ive never encountered these type of constraints, but if i had to keep warmed up the system, I would increase in each framework/sgbd the time before a resource is released. Not really easy to identify.

Comment: Do not forget that sgbd have a lot of parameter to optimize request (like keeping some tables in memory and flushing on disk when necessary) and, as it consumes resources, sgbd can release it too. A bad approach would be to insert ping data at scheduled time in order to keep all warmed up